# Move to next iteration in WHILE loop SQL-PL DB2

Tags: while-loop, db2, iteration, sql-pl

Is there a way to tell a program to move to the next iteration of a while loop in SQL-PL for DB2? I know that there is a CONTINUE statement, but it isn't working for me.

I basically want:

```
WHILE .... DO
    IF condition_met THEN
        -- Move to next iteration of the while loop
    END IF;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: I think you mean SQL-PL? "PL/SQL" is the Oracle language

Comment: Version and platform of DB2?

Comment: Yep you are correct Tony. And I am running 9.7 Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [ITERATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005650.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-164) command in the Knowledge Center.  The ITERATE statement causes the flow of control to return to the beginning of a labelled loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The ITERATE command worked for me. I also had to add a LABEL to my while loop so that I could use the ITERATE command.